# C# WCF self-hosting opened but refused by browsers

Tags: c#, wcf, https, self-hosting

I've a WCF self-hosted inside a Windows Service which runs as Local System.
WCF configuration is done programmaticaly (means without app.config configuration).

This WCF service host is opened correctly whithout any exceptions and I can see 2 final endpoints in debug mode (main endpoint and mex endpoint for metadata).

When I open web browser (IE) to my main endpoint "https://myserver.mydomain.fr:443/endpoint" , I get error "This page can't be displayed". If I run a IE network diagnostic, I got: "This driver or remote ressource is not configured to accept connections on port https"

Url has been reserved with netsh http add urlacl url=https://myserver.mydomain.fr:443/endpoint/ and certificate has been attached to port 443 correctly (with GUID of this Windows Service and certificate thumbprint).

Do you know where I shoud focus my effort? On WCF configuration?
It worked but stop working some days ago...

**UPDATE1**: Here is my code.

My main ServiceHost class is:

```
public class CustomServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    private string _AssembyIDOfWindowsService=String.Empty;
    private string _mainEndPointRelativeAddress = String.Empty;
    private string _mexRelativeAddress = "mex";

    public CustomServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses, string mainEndPointRelativeAddress, string mexRelativeAddress)
    : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {
        _mainEndPointRelativeAddress = mainEndPointRelativeAddress;
        _mexRelativeAddress = mexRelativeAddress;
    }

    protected override void InitializeRuntime()
    {
        //Add Service debug behavior
        AddServiceDebugBehavior();

        //Add main endpoint and mex endpoint
        AddEndpoints();

        //Configure throttling: means number max of connections, sessions and objects
        ConfigureThrottling();

        //Allow clients to connect without client certificates
        Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

            Base.InitializeRuntime(); //My error was here... WTF... So easy...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add main endpoint on wer server and mex endpoint for operations signatures
    /// </summary>
    private void AddEndpoints()
    {
        BasicHttpsBinding basicHttpsBinding = WcfHelpers.ConfigureBasicHttpsBinding();

        foreach (Uri address in this.BaseAddresses)
        {
            //Create endpoint with or without an endpoint name (ie https://myserver.mydomain.fr/443 or https://myserver.mydomain.fr/443/endpoint )
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(
                ContractDescription.GetContract(Description.ServiceType),
                basicHttpsBinding,
                new EndpointAddress(address + _mainEndPointRelativeAddress));

            //Add main service endpoint to service
            AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint);

            //adding behavior
            AddServiceMetadataBehavior();

            //adding mex endpoint (address.AbsoluteUri always finish with \ so not needed between base address and mexRelativeEndpoint
            AddServiceEndpoint(
                ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding(),
                address.AbsoluteUri + _mexRelativeAddress);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add debug behavior if not already done
    /// </summary>
    private void AddServiceDebugBehavior()
    {
        ServiceDebugBehavior debugBehavior = Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();

        if (debugBehavior == null)
        {
            Description.Behaviors.Add(
                new ServiceDebugBehavior() { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });
        }
        else
        {
            if (!debugBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults)
                debugBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add service metadata behavior
    /// </summary>
    private void AddServiceMetadataBehavior()
    {
        ServiceMetadataBehavior metadataBehavior = Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

        if (metadataBehavior == null)
        {
            ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceMetadataBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            serviceMetadataBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
            Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetadataBehavior);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure max numbers of concurrent accesses (calls, instances and sessions)
    /// </summary>
    private void ConfigureThrottling()
    {
        ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttleBehavior = Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceThrottlingBehavior>();

        if (throttleBehavior != null) return;

        throttleBehavior = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 100, // MaxConcurrentCalls should be set to less than the SQL connection pool size in queued scenarios
            MaxConcurrentInstances = 100,
            MaxConcurrentSessions = 100
        };

        Description.Behaviors.Add(throttleBehavior);
    }
}
```

To configure httpsbinding, I use this one:

```
/// <summary>
/// Used by server and clients to define common bindings (thats why its a static method)
/// </summary>
public class WcfHelpers
{
    public static BasicHttpsBinding ConfigureBasicHttpsBinding()
    {
        BasicHttpsBinding basicHttpsBinding;

        basicHttpsBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding
        {
            Name = "myBasicHttpsBinding",

            OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
            CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
            SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
            MaxBufferPoolSize = 104857600,
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 104857600,
            Namespace = "https://myserver.mydomain.fr/443/endpoint",
            ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
            {
                MaxDepth = 104857600,
                MaxStringContentLength = 104857600,
                MaxArrayLength = 104857600,
                MaxBytesPerRead = 104857600,
                MaxNameTableCharCount = 104857600
            },
            Security =
            {
                Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport
            }
        };
        return basicHttpsBinding;
    }
}
```

An finally I create my ServiceHost like this:

```
//Create my ServiceHost
CustomServiceHost _serviceHost = new CustomServiceHost(typeof(WCF_Service_Library.Service)
                        , new Uri[] { new Uri("https://myserver.mydomain.fr:443/") }
                        , "endpoint"
                        , "mex");

//Attach a selected X509 certificate (X509Certificate2 certFound)
_serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = certFound;

//Open ServiceHost
_serviceHost.Open();

...

//Close ServiceHost
_serviceHost.Close();
```

**UPDATE2**: WCF log file is:

```
<events><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:55:54.1825288Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" RelatedActivityID="{de1073e0-a063-4b78-a802-e2ea11c2711d}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Start">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:55:54.1985712Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{de1073e0-a063-4b78-a802-e2ea11c2711d}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Start"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Limite d'activité.</Description><AppDomain>Windows Service</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Construire ServiceHost 'WCF_Service_Library.Service'.</ActivityName><ActivityType>Construct</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>524326</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:55:54.1985712Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{de1073e0-a063-4b78-a802-e2ea11c2711d}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.GetServiceElement.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Obtenir ServiceElement.</Description><AppDomain>Windows Service</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/ServiceConfigurationTraceRecord"><FoundServiceElement>False</FoundServiceElement></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:55:54.2135766Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{de1073e0-a063-4b78-a802-e2ea11c2711d}" RelatedActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Stop">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:55:54.2135766Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{de1073e0-a063-4b78-a802-e2ea11c2711d}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Stop"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Limite d'activité.</Description><AppDomain>Windows Service</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Construire ServiceHost 'WCF_Service_Library.Service'.</ActivityName><ActivityType>Construct</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:55:54.2765741Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" RelatedActivityID="{c002e9ab-b644-4f63-8efe-ce7b77e403e3}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Start">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:55:54.2765741Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{c002e9ab-b644-4f63-8efe-ce7b77e403e3}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Start"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Limite d'activité.</Description><AppDomain>Windows Service</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Ouvrir ServiceHost 'WCF_Service_Library.Service'.</ActivityName><ActivityType>Open</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>524333</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:55:54.2765741Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{c002e9ab-b644-4f63-8efe-ce7b77e403e3}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBaseAddresses.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Adresses de base ServiceHost.</Description><AppDomain>Windows Service</AppDomain><Source>Windows_Service.CustomServiceHost/45867655</Source><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/CollectionTraceRecord"><BaseAddresses><Address>https://myserver.mydomain.fr:443/</Address></BaseAddresses></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:55:54.2765741Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{c002e9ab-b644-4f63-8efe-ce7b77e403e3}" RelatedActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Stop">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:55:54.2765741Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{c002e9ab-b644-4f63-8efe-ce7b77e403e3}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Stop"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Limite d'activité.</Description><AppDomain>Windows Service</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Ouvrir ServiceHost 'WCF_Service_Library.Service'.</ActivityName><ActivityType>Open</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:56:09.3075479Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" RelatedActivityID="{19dd45d9-e0f7-4ffe-aa8e-4aaf7b5b18ba}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Start">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:56:09.3075479Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{19dd45d9-e0f7-4ffe-aa8e-4aaf7b5b18ba}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Start"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Limite d'activité.</Description><AppDomain>Windows Service</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Fermer ServiceHost 'WCF_Service_Library.Service'.</ActivityName><ActivityType>Close</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>524333</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:56:09.3075479Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{19dd45d9-e0f7-4ffe-aa8e-4aaf7b5b18ba}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBaseAddresses.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Adresses de base ServiceHost.</Description><AppDomain>Windows Service</AppDomain><Source>Windows_Service.CustomServiceHost/45867655</Source><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/CollectionTraceRecord"><BaseAddresses><Address>https://myserver.mydomain.fr:443/</Address></BaseAddresses></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>0</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Transfer">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:56:09.3075479Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{19dd45d9-e0f7-4ffe-aa8e-4aaf7b5b18ba}" RelatedActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131085</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Stop">0</SubType><Level>255</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:56:09.3075479Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{19dd45d9-e0f7-4ffe-aa8e-4aaf7b5b18ba}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="4" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Stop"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ActivityBoundary.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Limite d'activité.</Description><AppDomain>Windows Service</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><ActivityName>Fermer ServiceHost 'WCF_Service_Library.Service'.</ActivityName><ActivityType>Close</ActivityType></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131073</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:56:09.4795464Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="2" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Information"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.AppDomainUnload.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Déchargement d'un domaine d'application.</Description><AppDomain>Windows Service</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/DictionaryTraceRecord"><AppDomain.FriendlyName>Windows Service</AppDomain.FriendlyName><ProcessName>Windows Service</ProcessName><ProcessId>6676</ProcessId></ExtendedData></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131073</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Information">0</SubType><Level>8</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-19T09:56:09.4795464Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" /><Execution ProcessName="Windows Service" ProcessID="6676" ThreadID="2" /><Channel/><Computer>DEV01</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord Severity="Information" Channel="Debug" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.AppDomainUnload.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Déchargement AppDomain. AppDomain.FriendlyName Windows Service, ProcessName Windows Service, ProcessId 6676.</Description><AppDomain>Windows Service</AppDomain></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent></events>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Enable WCF tracing and also use Fiddler. That might show some hints on what to move on next.

Comment: Thanks, I do it right now! :)

Comment: Out of my curiosity, did you need to set up a firewall exception or what?

Comment: No firewall exception needed.... My FW is on.

Comment: Ok, I've seen one strange information trace before ServiceHost.Open(): Get ServiceElement returns FoundServiceElement=False... I don't have ServiceHostFactory... Is-it related to ?

Comment: (fyi Local system doesn't need url reservation, local service would require it, but it's ok) Restart your windows host service, share the code of the win service, attach log handler on wcf opening... check also netstat

Comment: @Machine Learning: Ok, noted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall and restart the host service.

Implement the following wcf handlers

```
serviceHost.Opening += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Opening);
serviceHost.Opened += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Opened);
serviceHost.Closing += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Closing);
serviceHost.Closed += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Closed);
serviceHost.Faulted += new EventHandler(serviceHost_Faulted);
serviceHost.UnknownMessageReceived += new EventHandler<UnknownMessageReceivedEventArgs>(serviceHost_UnknownMessageReceived);

serviceHost.Open();
```

Check also the windows events and netstat

```
netstat -aon | find ":443"
```

to find if the port binding is actually active and what program belongs to that PID.

Please note, don't close the service host after opening it (open wcp in the windows service `OnStart` and close it in `OnStop`)

Look also at msdn example for [specifying endpoint address in code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3)

```
Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/HelloService");
string address = "http://localhost:8000/HelloService/MyService";

using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloService), baseAddress))
{
    serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHello), new BasicHttpBinding(), address);
    serviceHost.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to terminate service");
    Console.ReadLine();
    serviceHost.Close();
}
```

A final note, I expect you should add

```
base.InitializeRuntime();
```

in the end of `protected override void InitializeRuntime()`

Comment: I've reinstalled and restarted several times. No changes. And no Windows events errors or warnings.

Comment: If netstat return no results => the wcf service is not listening to the port, this is important. What about wcf handlers' logs: have you implemted them? (I'm reading your question updates... I'll possibly edit my answer)

Comment: I haven't implemented yet handlers but I will. I've added WCF log file in UPDATE2... Thanks for your guideline... You help me a lot!

Comment: Ok, I've implemented these handlers and only 2 are called on start (CustomerServiceHost_Opening and CustomerServiceHost_Opened) and 2 on stop: (CustomerServiceHost_Closing and CustomerServiceHost_Closed). So, sounds good on these fired events...

Comment: I've a doubt on what should I put in ConfigureBasicHttpsBinding().Namespace. Is it full url with endpoint? Means "https://myserver.mydomain.fr/443/endpoint"...

Comment: Do you mean the endpoint address? I've edited my answer to include an example of specifying it in code...

Comment: Thanks for clarification, the serviceHost.Open() is called on Windows Service OnStart() and serviceHost.Close() is called on OnStop(). No, I was talking about value to be defined in Namespace of a basicHttpsBinding.

Comment: Well, maybe the .svclog you attached get corrupted in my download, but I'd say there _could_ be an issue in the endpoint address construction, since I see "`TraceIdentifier http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-FR/library/System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBaseAddresses.aspx`". That's why I'm suggesting to temporary replacing your CustomServiceHost with a standard `ServiceHost` + `AddServiceEndpoint`. Hope it helps spotting where the problem is

Comment: Ok, I understand and I try... Thanks Machine Learning! :)

Comment: You were right... It seems that the issue was when I used ServiceEndPoint constructor with ContractDescription.GetContract(Description.ServiceType). The corruption was here. I've to rearrange all these pièces of code together to have a solution... Thanks again!!!

Comment: Thank you! I think you have to add base.InitializeRuntime(); in the end of InitializeRuntime

Comment: HOW COULD I MISS THAT!!! :) Thanks Machine Learning, all is working fine now with my previous code...